# While trying to install Ubuntu on my chromebook I get the "illegal option" error

Tags: scripts, chromebook

```
Loading extra module: /usr/share/crosh/dev.d/50-crosh.sh
Welcome to crosh, the Chrome OS developer shell.

If you got here by mistake, don't panic!  Just close this tab and carry on.

Type 'help' for a list of commands.

If you want to customize the look/behavior, you can use the options page.
Load it by using the Ctrl+Shift+P keyboard shortcut.
crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh -/Downloads/Crout -e -t xfce

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

    sh: Illegal option -/
    chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh -/Downloads/Crout -e -t xfce
    sh: Illegal option -/
    chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh -/Downloads/crouton -e -t xfce
    sh: Illegal option -/
    chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh -/Downloads/crouton -e -t xfce
    sh: Illegal option -/
    chronos@localhost / $
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details. It's hard to read and we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately Crouton procedures are considered "not Ubuntu" and thus off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You misread the [instructions for installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Crouton-on-Your-Chromebook). The correct command is supposed to be:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -e -t xfce # the -e flag is optional and can be omitted
```

Where a tilde character `~` instead of a hyphen is used as an abbreviation for your home directory. (example: `~/Downloads` is equivalent to `/home/your-username/Downloads`)